# Why does max-height work in Chrome but not in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created the page below, and I want my green divs to expand downward without affecting the row below. To achieve this, I styled the **.grid_cell** div with **max-height: 164px;** so that anything contained within the grid_cell class would overflow downward without changing the height of grid_cell. Is there any way I can get this to work in IE 11 the way it works in Chrome? If you open this page in IE 11 you'll notice that when you hover over a div, it pushes the div below it downward, but in Chrome that does not happen. Why is that?

https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/Test_TeamSlideshow.html

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-nav-prev,
.flex-nav-next {
  display: none;
}


/*hide the left and right arrows*/

#BackgroundContainer {
  background-color: white;
  height: 1180px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flexslider {
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: none !important;
  /*overrides the flexslider.css file style*/
}

.flex-viewport {
  width: 820px;
  height: 750px;
}

.flex-active-slide {
  width: 820px;
}

#slider {
  background: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*overrides the flexslider.css file style*/
  min-height: 370px;
  /*no longer necessary? this reserves height for the slider and makes sure that the blurb at the bottom stays there as the page loads*/
}

#carousel {
  height: 40px;
  width: 910px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#carousel li {
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel span {
  font-family: comfortaa;
  color: #165D7A;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Team_Container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid_cell {
  max-height: 164px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.grid_cell:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid_cell div:hover {
  /*when the user hovers over the profile-containing div*/
  height: 343px;
  background-color: rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.9) !important;
  /*purplish blue almost opaque*/
  border-color: #7795BF !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 1px grey;
}

.grid_cell div div:hover {
  height: 160px;
}


/*when the user hovers over the picture-containing inner div*/

.profile_container {
  height: 163px;
  width: 144px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgba(207, 232, 221, 0.6);
  /*light green almost transparent*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #99D1E0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.profile_container span {
  display: block;
  width: 123px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa' !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.profile_container .employee_name {
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #395880;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  word-spacing: 120px;
  width: 130px;
}

.profile_container .job_title {
  line-height: 17px;
}

.pic_container {
  height: 130px;
  width: 124px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.profile_pic {
  height: 160px;
}

.department_description_container {
  width: 780px;
  min-height: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#DAE0E3, #C1D3DB);
  border: solid 2px #7F9AAD;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.department_description {
  font-family: comfortaa;
  color: #304F5E;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/jquery1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/ProductionPayrollHomeFlexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script defer src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/flexslider.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://shampouya.5gbfree.com/carousel.js"></script>
<!--referred to as modernizr.js in the flexslider package-->

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet'>


<div id="BackgroundContainer">
  <br>
  <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Department1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Department2</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <div class="Team_Container">
          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person1 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person2 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person3 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person4 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person5 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person6 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person7 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person8 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person9 LastName</span> <br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person10 LastName</span> <br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person11 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person12 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person13 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="department_description_container">
            <span class="department_description">Department 1 does X, Y, and Z.</span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="Team_Container">
          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person1 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person2 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person3 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person4 LastName</span> <br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person5 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person6 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person7 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person8 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person9 LastName</span> <br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid_cell">
            <div class="profile_container">
              <div class="pic_container"></div>
              <span class="employee_name">Person10 LastName</span><br>
              <span class="job_title">Job Position</span>
              <span>Department</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="department_description_container">
            <span class="department_description">Department 2 does U, V, and W.</span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in IE 11, max- CSS is applied correctly.

But IE11 regards sibling elements have the same z-index, so they are not stackable in view.

If you want to show that page properly in IE, edit CSS as following:

```
.grid_cell {
  width: 144px;
  height: 165px;
}

.profile_container {
  position: absolute;
}
```